# Edit multiple files in single commit with GitHub API

Tags: c#, git, github, github-api, git-commit

I'm using the GitHub API in a C# webapp (with Blazor). I want to be able to create a single commit to add, delete, and edit multiple files in a folder in a repository. I know I can send a PUT request to the URL `https://api.github.com/repos/[username]/[repository]/contents/[file]` with these contents to create a file (and I can also edit a file by adding an SHA hash):

```
{
    "message": "[Commit message]",
    "content": "[Content encoded in base64]",
    "committer": {
        "name": "[Committer name]",
        "email": "[Committer email]"
    }
}
```

But this creates one commit for every file change. Is there any way that I can do multiple operations in a single commit (either using the GitHub API or something else)? I would use something like libgit2sharp but I don't want to be cloning the repository to a folder on the filesystem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can do multiple operations in a single commit (either using the GitHub API or something else)?

There is the underlying [Git Data API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/) that can be used to build up a commit from scratch:

- files are uploaded as [blobs](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/) using the API
- [trees](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/) are used to indicate what the repository state should be (update paths to point to the new blobs)
- then create a new [commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/) using the new root tree and additional metadata
- if you can, then update the [reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/) (i.e. the branch) to point to this new commit

Comment: Hi Brendan, does this require (especially the tree step) the repository to be cloned, doesn't?

Comment: I believe, that this works, but could you give a very easy 2 file example, with all requests necessary.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [Git Flow](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/github-flow) with the GitHub API:

1. Create a new branch by [creating a ref](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/refs#create-a-reference) (e.g. `refs/heads/myNewBranch`), using the SHA of whichever base branch you want.
2. Make content changes in that branch ([create/update](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents) or [delete](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#delete-a-file) files). Be sure to set the `branch` parameter to your new branch name.
3. Create a [pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#create-a-pull-request) using your new branch as the head.
4. [Merge](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#merge-a-pull-request) the pull request with a merge_method of "squash". This will squash all the commits from individual content change API calls into 1 commit with your commit message of choice.