# is it possible to squash commits via Github API?

Tags: github-api, squash, git-squash, github-graphql

I've successfully implemented automatic file creation/update via Github V3 Rest API, however the only downside is that for each file I have a commit.

There is a possibility to do the same for multiple [files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583403/edit-multiple-files-in-single-commit-with-github-api), but unfortunately it involves some concepts I still haven't mastered and it will take me some time until I get there since I have more urgents stuff on my TODO list.

In the meanwhile, I can totally live with that or simply squash the last N commits, which I imagined should be relatively easy, since locally it's just a matter of

```
git reset --soft HEAD~N
git commit -m ".."
```

but I couldn't find anything on the docs or online

So my question is: how can I squash the last N commits, non interactively, using Github API?

Ps: I don't care if it's v3 or v4 as long as I get it done

Comment: `using Github API?` but why not using actual _git_?

Comment: Because this way I don't have to have the project cloned locally

Comment: If you don't want an answer that says "use Git", don't use the [tag:git] tag.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was still somehow related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not see a squash feature directly through API.

You would need to:

- [create a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9513594/6309) at HEAD-N commits, through the [create ref API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-reference)
- [reset your current branch to HEAD-N sha](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#update-a-reference), with force boolean parameter set to true?
- [create a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-merge-methods-on-github#squashing-your-merge-commits) from your new branch to your old reset branch
- [merge the PR](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#merge-a-pull-request), with the `merge_method` parameter set to squash

Pretty convoluted, but it should work (entirely through script, without having to clone the repository).

Answer (score 1):

I created a small service (https://squasher.nomeata.de/) that squashes commits on a branch, and it uses the Github API to do so:

- It gets information about the PR via `repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pr}`, in particular base and head ref.
- It gets the merge base using `repos/{head_repo_owner}/{head_repo_name}/compare/{base_label}...{head_label}`
- It gets the tree of the head branch using `repos/{head_repo_owner}/{head_repo_name}/git/commits/{head_sha}`
- It creates a new, squashed commit using `repos/{head_repo_owner}/{head_repo_name}/git/commits`
- It force-updates the head branch to that commit using `repos/{head_repo_owner}/{head_repo_name}/git/refs/heads/{head_ref}`

Full code at https://github.com/nomeata/squasher/blob/1ccc24a5768e663199f8805b59120a6160592cae/squasher.py#L44-L109

Comment: Interesting alternative, upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile it seems you can squash via API by setting `merge_method` to `squash`

see https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#merge-a-pull-request