# Is it possible to publish a file one way to a github folder using github API or another method?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I'd like to be able to publish to Github one way. I've read part of the API [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/quickstart) at  https://docs.github.com/en/rest/quickstart.

It looks like it's possible to read resources from github using this API but I didn't see if it's possible to publish to a repository.

I believe I'd need the user to have git installed and run that. But I'm in a web based environment. That web based environment can't access or run local git calls.

Since my goal is only to push a complete set of files (no diffs) to a specific repository folder, is that possible with the github API?

For example, consider a web form that has an upload feature. In the web page you choose a file with a file input and then send that file with a network request like so:

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
request.addEventListener('load', responseHandler, false);
request.open('POST', '/upload', true);
request.send(formData);

I want to do the same thing. Basically, upload a file or files to a folder in my repository. I can probably reuse the credentials if I'm logged into Github in another tab or authorize through github login.

**UPDATE:**
This is for the user to be able to post to their own repository not mine.  The use case is that the user wants one way write support to a directory of their repository (the github pages directory). They don't need diffs or git or anything else because they are creating the content on their local machine.

Comment: This feels like a misuse of Git?

Comment: See: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/commits?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-commit and https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/trees?apiVersion=2022-11-28

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61704866/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D+commit+file

Comment: @ikegami If the user is logged in then they may be able to reuse the session. but now that I think about it, this is not unlike a form on github.com with an upload button. and obviously, it can't be insecure lol

Comment: @matt maybe but related to git where git may not be available

Comment: @ikegami they would be posting to their own repository not mine. i'll update the question details. they would use my app to post. i will have to figure out authorization. but i believe that github has app authorization. but, if it's their own repo that should reuse logged in credentials maybe. see new notes. ie publishing to github pages.

Comment: @jessehouwing that looks promising

Comment: You can use an Oauth app on github so allow them to authenticate and grant your app access. https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/authenticating-to-the-rest-api-with-an-oauth-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a OAuth app which people will have to install into their account. You can initiate that installation flow from your app.

[An Oauth app will let you act on behalf the logged in user.](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/authenticating-to-the-rest-api-with-an-oauth-app) This sounds like the scenario you're after.

With the OAuth token in hand, you can [call create or update file API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents) to upload the new file.

```js
// Octokit.js
// https://github.com/octokit/core.js#readme
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: 'YOUR-TOKEN'
})

await octokit.request('PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}', {
  owner: 'OWNER',
  repo: 'REPO',
  path: 'PATH',
  message: 'my commit message',
  committer: {
    name: 'Monalisa Octocat',
    email: 'octocat@github.com'
  },
  content: 'bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM=',
  headers: {
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
  }
})
```