# How to update multiple files in single commit with Gitlab API in C#

Tags: c#, rest, web, blazor, gitlab-api

I'm using the Gitlab Rest API in a C# webapp (with Blazor). I want to be able to create a single commit to add, delete, and edit multiple files in a folder in a repository. Is there any reference/example to:

- Upload file & update existing file/s
- Update tree repository status
- Create commit to the branch in C#?

Tried using commits API . But need help on how to upload file and update tree repository status for the particular branch

Reference checked in stackoverflow which was related to Github : [Edit multiple files in single commit with GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583403/edit-multiple-files-in-single-commit-with-github-api/61704866#61704866)

Need help with Gitlab API.